# How to convert numbers into alphabets in c++

Tags: c++

What is the problem with the below code ?
I want to convert 1 into A , 2 into B and so on.
But the output I am getting is "q r s" when I enter "1 2 3"

```
void main()
{
clrscr();
char arr[20];

gets(arr);
cout<<endl;

for(int j=0;arr[j]!='\0';j++)
{

    if(arr[j]==' ')   //neglect the space character
    {}
    else
    cout<<(char)(arr[j]+64) <<" ";
}

getch();
```

}

//output:
q r s

Comment: When you input numbers into a string they aren't numbers, they are the ascii codes for those numbers.

Comment: `49 + 64 == 113`, which is `q`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at the [ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/) table, you will notice that the 'letter' `1` has decimal number 49 and the 'letter' `A` has decimal number 65. **The difference is 16**, not 64.

Answer (score 0):

the short answer is that most compilers today use the ASCII standards, so the numbers entered are correlating with whatever the character is for that number in the ASCII table.

Comment: ASCII is rarely a limitation. Particularly since C++ standards have long required them to allow letters from many writing systems in identifiers.